# React displaying TreeNode

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

I would like to generate TreeNode like below in React.

```
<TreeNode>
    <TreeNode>
        <TreeNode>
        </TreeNode>
    </TreeNode>
</TreeNode>
```

Below is the code i tried

```
const numberVal = [1,2,3];
function renderPage(){
return(numberVal.map((n, i) => (
    <TreeNode></TreeNode>
  )));
}
```

It is displaying like below:

```
<TreeNode></TreeNode>
<TreeNode></TreeNode>
<TreeNode></TreeNode>
```

Could anyone let me know the way in which can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use recursion:

```
const numberVal = [1,2,3];
function renderPage(){

  const processData = array => {

    if(array.length)  {
      const [first, ...rest] = array || [];
      return (
        <TreeNode>
          {processData(rest)}
        </TreeNode>
      )
    }
    return null;
  }

  return processData(numberVal);
}
```

Comment: I think it does not answer my question . Since i wanted it to display the same treeNode tag in different way

Comment: Try now. just one div needed to rename

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. While building a node, include the children structure and let it include them inside if present

```js
const makeNodes([nodeId, ...children]) {
  return (
    <TreeNode id={nodeId}>
    { children ? makeNodes(children) : null }
    </TreeNode>
  );
}

render() {
  const a = [1,2,3];
  return makeNodes(a);
}
```

This way you can make even more complex structures like this:

```js
render() {
  const a = [ [1,2,3], [4], [5,6] ];
  return (
    <div>
    { a.map(nodes => makeNodes(nodes)) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

and it should produce

```
  <TreeNode id=1>
    <TreeNode id=2>
      <TreeNode id=3>
      </TreeNode>
    </TreeNode>
  </TreeNode>
  <TreeNode id=4>
  </TreeNode>
  <TreeNode id=5>
    <TreeNode id=6>
    </TreeNode>
  </TreeNode>
```

Note that this code wasn't actually run and might have syntax errors - consider it pseudo-code.